# Call by name vs Call by value in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If call by value and call by name works, does both of the them  delivers the same result?
For example:

```
import Debug.Trace 
trace :: String -> a -> a 
foo x y z = y + y + z
 z = foo (trace "first" 1) 
    (trace "second" 2)
    (trace "third" 3) 

 Call-By-Value: "first second third" 7
 Call-By-Name: "second second third" 7
  Lazy Evaluation: "second third" 7
```

Is this case we will get three different results, but why?

Comment: there seems to be quite some things missing from your code ... how do you produce the 3 results?

Comment: anyway you should be able to guess why ... obviously you don't have to evaluate `x` to produce the result - so non-strict evaluation won't - now what is the feature you get with *lazy evaluation* on top?

Comment: Hello, this code is written by  Prof

Comment: so it's homework - I guess s/he told you the differences between those strategies right?

Comment: the article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Non-strict_evaluation) on this seems really good - did you check it out yet?

Comment: Yes, but the point is. i thought in Haskell it does not matter, if call by value and call by name works, then both of them deliver the same result? So i am  confused

Comment: the result is `7` every time right? ... the difference is that you have to evaluate the terms 0-2 times as you see ... the result stays the same

Comment: **see**: the stuff in `".."` is supposed to be *debugging info*: `Debug.Trace (trace)` ;) - it tells you a bit about how your computer is calculating the result  ...

Comment: Fun fact: even in C++, you cannot know in what order the arguments will get evaluated: `foo(bar(), baz()` could invoke `bar` or `baz` first (but both _will_ be called!). This is one of the reasons C++14 introduced `make_unique`, since `foo(std::unique_ptr<widget>(new widget(...)), g())` will leak memory if `new widget(...)` gets called first, `g` throws an exception, and `std::unique_ptr` never gets constructed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you got the same result every time: `7`.

The other messages ("first", etc.) are due to the use of the *debugging* function `Debug.Trace.trace`, which is used to produce a message which exposes exactly how the expression is being evaluated. The "how" part of programming execution is generally not considered to be part of the semantics, i.e. of the result, which instead considers only "what" is being returned.

For instance, the semantics of

```
let f x = x in f 10 + f 10
```

is 20, the same as

```
let f x = x in 2 * f 10
```

However, if we add traces,

```
let f x = trace "msg" x in f 10 + f 10
```

prints "msg" twice since we call the function twice. Instead,

```
let f x = trace "msg" x in 2 * f 10
```

prints "msg" only once. This merely shows that the evaluation is done differently, not that the result is different.

In normal, "production" code, programmers are not supposed to rely on debugging aids such as those in the `Debug.*` modules to produce messages. Indeed, that would break many nice properties of pure functional programming, and should only be used for debugging purposes.